# Can we use SQL Server 2019 Big Data Cluster as Data Warehouse?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to compare the solutions to create Data Warehouse which is around 20 TB using Microsoft products on both On-Premises and Azure. I have checked the SQL Server 2019 Big Data Clusters but got some questions. Can we use this product as Data Warehouse for On-Premises? What are the disadvantages & advantages we have on this product?

Comment: hi, I just would like to make you notice that Big Data Cluster has been retired: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2022/02/big-data-clusters-out-of-aces/

Answer (score 0):

The [SQL Server 2019 Big Data Clusters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/big-data-cluster-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) adoption must be so little that no one replied to you.

I'm sorry, I think this Microsoft product didn't receive much attention from the public and it might be like [PolyBase](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-guide?view=sql-server-ver15) another good product that didn't received much attention.

If you check the documentation of both links they have been updated on the same date 09/21/2021.

This is probably because the products might have received an automatic layout editing but these products haven't been updated for a long time and they will eventually be deprecated in the next few years.

If I can reply to your question the main difference are:

- **SQL Server 2019 Big Data Clusters:** you have to maintain it, so you have to pay engineers. And on top of that you have to pay for the SQL Server Licensing, [Link1](https://mohammaddarab.com/sql-server-licensing-for-big-data-clusters/), [Link2](https://www.dcac.com/blog/sql-server-2019-big-data-and-licensing)
- **Azure Synapse Analytics:** you don't have to maintain it but it will cost you [a lot](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/synapse-analytics/), especially under heavy calculation.

**EDIT:** Big Data Cluster is no more an option to you, [it has been retired](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2022/02/big-data-clusters-out-of-aces/).